# How do I bend half of a pane to match slope of adjacent pane?

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh, blender-osm

I am trying to bend half of a pane so that it matches the Pane adjacent to it.

[image: Half of the pan should follow the slope upwards]

[image: The Pane should match something like this]

I've tried multiple ways and have so far failed to match the required shape.
It must also be python scriptable.

Answer (score 0):

What I did end up doing was rotating it about the centre and using trigonometry to find how much the shape was displaced due to the rotation. I then moved the shape up that same amount.